# Sidekiq -r a single demo_worker.rb file, and require active support in that worker doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, activesupport

I wanted to require active_support in my demo_worker.rb.

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'active_support'

class DemoWorker
end
```

And then I ran `sidekiq -r ./demo_worker.rb`

It told me that cannot require active_support, I also tried to require rails, but still wasn't working at all. How do I require active_support in the plain mode of sidekiq?

this is the exact error that I got

```
cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext (LoadError)
```

I've looked around, couldnt find something helpful.

Comment: Are you adding Sidekiq as a gem in a Rails application ?

Comment: No, it's just a single ruby file, named demo_worker.

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @KamilGwóźdź Yep, I did. And I've also tried to 'active_support', 'active_support/all', 'rails', turned out to be the same error

Comment: cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext (LoadError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens cause the gem `activesupport` has not been installed yet (on your local machine), so just run command `gem install activesupport`, and it'll be ok.

But note that `active_support` in Rails use `autoload` so if we're going to use it's submodules outside Rails we need to require them directly, for example i want to use extension `Integer#hours` i need to require `active_support/core_ext/integer/time`

```rb
require 'sidekiq'
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

class Demo
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(how_hard="super hard", how_long=1)
    sleep how_long
    puts "Workin' #{how_hard} #{8.hours}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Learned about autoload and require, now I know how it works~!!